# No directory listing index page

Tags: seo, noindex, directory-listing, assets

I have some audio assets directories on my website. The server allows directory listing. i.e. all audio files will be listed if the user visited `example.com/assets/audio/nature/`. I don't want to change any server's configurations, so, I will place an `index.html` inside every assets audio directory to prevent listing.

I worry about the any SEO negative effect of that. The index file code is very simple as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>No Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        <a href="/" style="color:green;">Home Page</a>
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Does the meta tag `robots` in the above snippet enough to prevent any SEO issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally fine from an SEO standpoint.

You're telling the crawlers not to index these "No Index" pages, so that's just what they'll do.

Ideally you would configure the server to return a "403 Forbidden" status code so that non-search crawlers get the idea too, but in practice it probably does not really matter.